# What is the correct use of $and operator in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have this structure:

```
>>>test_3.find_one({"humsavar.Disease": {"$exists": True}}, 
{"humsavar":True, "_id":False})

{u'humsavar': [{u'Association': u'Polymorphism',
   u'Disease': u'-',
   u'Gene names': u'DTWD1',
   u'Mutate aa': u'Pro',
   u'Position aa': 9,
   u'Reference aa': u'Leu',
   u'Substitution': u'Leu9Pro',
   u'SwissVarID': u'VAR_036757',
   u'Uniprot': u'Q8N5C7',
   u'dbSNP': u'rs11539522'},
  {u'Association': u'Polymorphism',
   u'Disease': u'Pyruvate dehydrogenase lipoic acid synthetase deficiency',
   u'Gene names': u'DTWD1',
   u'Mutate aa': u'Lys',
   u'Position aa': 13,
   u'Reference aa': u'Glu',
   u'Substitution': u'Glu13Lys',
   u'SwissVarID': u'VAR_036758',
   u'Uniprot': u'Q8N5C7',
   u'dbSNP': u'rs11539519'}]}
```

Should I search with the following query to count all the documents from humsavar with a Disease and dbSNP?

```
test_3.find({"$and": [{"humsavar.Disease": {"$ne": u'-', "$exists":  True}},
 {"humsavar.dbSNP": {"$ne": u'-', "$ne": None, "$exists":  True}}]},
{"humsavar":True, "_id": False}).count()
# output 32
```

I would expect a similar number with this query:

```
test_3.find({"$and": [{"humsavar.Disease": {"$ne": u'-', "$ne":None, "$exists":  True}},
 {"humsavar.dbSNP": {"$ne": u'-', "$ne": None, "$exists":  True}}]},
 {"humsavar":True, "_id": False}).count()
```

But turn out to be 8499

Comment: Did you try it? does it work? what's the problem then?

Comment: The problem is I don't known the properly use of the operator, I tried several combinations with $nor and $and

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your last query returns too many documents, because in python you cannot really include duplicate keys in a dict, like that:

```
{"$ne": u'-', "$ne":None, "$exists":  True}
```

This causes the second occurence of `"$ne"` to overwrite the first, ending with a dict of

```
{"$ne":None, "$exists":  True}
```

This all happens in the python-interpreter layer, before being passed to the pymongo driver.

If you want multiple `$ne` conditions on a single field, you can use the [`$nin`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) ("not in") operator instead.

Comment: Thanks, about the `$and` there are other ways of rewording this query or a better one?

Answer (score 2):

From MongoDB docs on [`$and`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) usage.

> MongoDB provides an implicit AND operation when specifying a comma separated list of expressions. Using an explicit AND with the $and operator is necessary when the same field or operator has to be specified in multiple expressions.

You only need to use `$and` operator for the duplicate field name. The condition for `humsaver.Disease`, `humsaver.dbSNP` and `humsavar` will be implicit. (Although using `$and` will give you the same result).

```
test_3.find(
    {"humsavar.Disease": 
        {'$and': [
            {"$ne": u'-'},
            { "$ne":None},
            { "$exists":  True}
        ]}
    },
    {"humsavar.dbSNP": 
        {'$and':[
            {"$ne": u'-'},
            { "$ne": None},
            { "$exists":  True}
        ]},
    },
    {"humsavar":True, "_id": False}
).count()
```